# Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'FormData' error when uploading file

Tags: flutter

I try to upload image to server but i have error `Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'FormData'`

My post method

```
 void _upload(File file) async {
        String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    
        FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
          "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            file.path,
            filename: fileName,
          ),
        });
    
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        await dio.post(apiEndpoint + "users/avatar",
            options: Options(headers: {
              "Authorization":
                  apiToken
            }),
            data: {
              "image": data,
            });
      }
```

What should i change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert any arbitrary class instance to JSON.

One option is to provide a custom function to the JsonEncoder() constructor (via the toEncodable argument). This custom function should map your custom objects to types that JsonEncoder already knows how to handle (i.e. numbers, strings, booleans, null, lists and maps with string keys).

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-convert/JsonEncoder-class.html

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable is a package that generates code for that so that you don't need to write it manually.

See also https://flutter.io/json/